# Get final rank from ranked list

Tags: ranking, ranks

i got exactly same problem with this question [Overall rank from multiple ranked lists](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56852/overall-rank-from-multiple-ranked-lists)
but i didnt get any references and answer for that.

example :

`object |    case 1   |  case 2    |  case 3   | case 4 
Item 1  |   Ranked 1  |  Ranked 1  |  Ranked 2 | Ranked 1
Item 2  |   Ranked 2  |  Ranked 2  |  Ranked 3 | Ranked 3
Item 3  |   Ranked 3  |  Ranked 3  |  Ranked 1 | Ranked 2`

visually we can say the final rank from all case is item 1 got first rank because got rank (1 1 2 1), item 3 got second rank (3 3 1 2), and item 2 got last rank (2 2 3 3).

Final rank :

`object |  final rank
Item 1  |   Ranked 1 
Item 2  |   Ranked 3 
Item 3  |   Ranked 2`

visually we can say that, but is there a statistical calculation to get the final result?
I have read the reference about friedman test. but it only deals with hypotheses to conclude whether their final rankings are the same or not. I get a solution to averaging its rankings but I need a clear reference like a journal for that. is there anybody can give me journal link that discusses about this? or discusses about averaging its rangkings?

Comment: Can't you just take the aggregate across the cases? Just take the mean for example? Also, what exactly was wrong with the first answer to the question you linked to? https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/56867/40604

Comment: I need references like journals and I have not got a journal that says can use an average for a case like this